# Pascal's Triangle - Remove hack

Tags: clojure

I had a thought last night on how I could easily write a Pascal's Triangle generator basically just using `partition` and `map`. I tried writing it this morning, and it got slightly more complicated than I originally thought it would, although it's still pretty nice.

My main concern is the `wrap` "hack" that I'm using. I found two similar, but different ways of writing it. I can either wrap the input to the iteration function in 0s, or I can wrap the result of the iteration function in 1s. Both give the same result, but the need for a wrapping helper pollutes an otherwise nice `->>` chain. If anyone can think of how I can avoid a separate anonymous function here, and ideally avoid wrapping the input/output in 0s/1s, I'd appreciate it. I'll take any other critique as well, although there isn't much else going on here.

Usage:

```
(let [pre-t (pascals-triangle-pre) ; Wrapping pre-processing
      post-t (pascals-triangle-post) ; Wrapping post-processing
      n 5]
  (println (take n pre-t))
  (println (take n post-t)))

([1] [1 1] [1 2 1] [1 3 3 1] [1 4 6 4 1])
([1] [1 1] [1 2 1] [1 3 3 1] [1 4 6 4 1])
```

---

```
(ns minesweeper.irrelevant.pas-tri)

(defn pascals-triangle-post []
  (let [wrap #(vec (concat [1] % [1]))]
    (iterate #(->> %
                   (partition 2 1)
                   (mapv (partial apply +'))
                   (wrap))
             [1])))

(defn pascals-triangle-pre []
  (let [wrap #(vec (concat [0] % [0]))]
    (iterate #(->> %
                   (wrap)
                   (partition 2 1)
                   (mapv (partial apply +')))
             [1])))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a simpler way.

To get the next line

- take two copies of the line,
- extend them respectively with `0` at the start and with `0` at the end, and
- add the corresponding elements.

In Clojure,

```
(defn pascal []
  (iterate
    #(mapv + (cons 0 %) (conj % 0))
    [1]))

=> (take 5 (pascal))
([1] [1 1] [1 2 1] [1 3 3 1] [1 4 6 4 1])
```

This avoids the `partition`ing.

---

Not sure if it's what you're looking for, but showing off was irresistible.